# Embeddable Cross-Platform Web Browser?

Tags: java, .net, c++, cross-platform, browser

I'm wondering if there is a Web Browser that I can embed in my Applications and that is cross-Platform (Windows, OS X, Linux)?

I'm undecided about the programming language, but I guess I'll have to go the C++ route (in which case I'd likely choose Qt as a GUI Framework) unless something for .net/mono or Java exists?

Doesn't need to be too fancy, but should ideally be free/open source. I know I could just grab the WebKit sources, but these are HUGE, and I wonder if they are really intended for embedding or if there is a browser that is already embeddable?

It does not have to be the latest and greatest, although Ogg Theora support would be excellent (or at least some way for me to add it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrey noted in his comment WebKit is itself embeddable. If you use Qt then you can easily embed it into your application using [QtWebKit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/webintegration.html).

Comment: Good suggestions, I went with this one in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have found this Webkit based browser:
[Arora](https://code.google.com/p/arora/)

Comment: I was going to say Arora as well. It's embeddable and its code is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a java solution, but you might want to look at jdic.

https://jdic.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse includes a web browser which you might be able to use.  I have no experience with actually using it, but it works ok for webpages inside Eclipse.